# Presto not using index with mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, presto

I have set up a Presto (0.191) instance with one Coordinator and one Worker node and want to do some data analysis with data from several sources like mysql and mongodb.

Wenn I do a query on the mongodb table "earnings" Presto **seems to do a full table scan and not have the Connector use the index** on "the_date":

```
select e._id from mongodb.database.earnings e where e.the_date between timestamp '2015-01-01 00:00 UTC' and timestamp '2015-01-02 00:00 UTC'
```

I read that predicate pushdown only works if there is no function involved in the predicates, so I created a memory table with one row containing the two timestamp fields I'm using in Where to join it with the query. The query looks like this and seems to be using the index:

```
select e._id from mongodb.reporting.dfpearnings e, memory.test.date_range dr where e.the_date between dr.begin and dr.excluding_end
```

Now if I want to group the data by day with `group by date(e.the_date)` it will do a full scan again.

**Is there a way to enforce the use of indexes?**

Comment: @Normali Were you able to find a solution with which PrestoDB used the index in MongoDB instead of doing the full table scan?

Comment: @ShubhamA. Only if you don't use any functions in the where clause.

Comment: I ran Mongo query with and without any Presto functions and performance was exactly the same. Can you point me out to the source which provided this info about not considering index when we use any functions in the where clause?